# Minimal example of uWSGI's shared memory?

Tags: python, django, shared-memory, uwsgi

Does anyone have a minimal working example of how to use uWSGI to share memory across requests in say Django?

I have a large file in proprietary format (not database-compatible) that I need to load for each request.

An [instagram](https://engineering.instagram.com/dismissing-python-garbage-collection-at-instagram-4dca40b29172#.t8xk3k4a5) post got me thinking which states:

> For the application server, we use uWSGI with pre-fork mode to leverage memory sharing between master and worker processes.

How would you set something like that up?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/bhtucker/41dbed0a4be941989a878e9a754ea18e

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to handle this:

## Share by "abusing" copy-on-write for read-only data

If your data is read-only, you can leverage the fact that uWSGI is executing your python code to get the `application` before forking into multiple processes. This means all the data that is already loaded before the fork happens will be shared with all your processes.

This can be a great tool because you don't have to do anything dealing with multi-processing to enjoy this mechanism. But be careful, as soon as any process writes to this data, it will copy it first to get its own local version.

Django doesn't make it easy because all the views are lazy. This means django won't try to run code related to your view when `application` is created. Therefore to enjoy the pre-fork sharing you need to load the data in a code outside your views. For instance you can consider loading the data right before or after you built your `application` object (like in the gist linked by @john-strood).

## Use uWSGI cache framework

If you need to write to this data, a first solution is to use [uWSGI cache framework](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Caching.html). It's fairly easy to use. You need to configure in advance how much memory you need, and then all your processes can read and write to it. You don't have to deal with locking or other multi-processing related issues.
The drawback is that you still incur IO latency between your processes and uWSGI cache's process. This is insignificant for tiny chunks of data, but would be prohibitive for gigabytes.

## Use shared memory manually

As a last resort, if your data is not read-only and you need to load large chunks at all request, so large that even sending through a unix socket would take too long, then you need to load your data directly in the shared memory space. Here uWSGI won't help, and you will have to deal with locking and multi-processing issues yourself.
You can refer to [multiprocessing's shared memory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

For pre-fork mode setting this should be enough:
`master = true`
However make sure that you have **NOT** set this one:
`lazy-apps = true` This would **PREVENT** preforking.